# C++ lambda with captures as a function pointer

Tags: c++, lambda, function-pointers, c++11

I was playing with C++ lambdas and their implicit conversion to function pointers. My starting example was using them as callback for the ftw function. This works as expected.

```
#include <ftw.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    auto callback = [](const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb,
        int typeflag) -> int {
        cout << fpath << endl;
        return 0;
    };

    int ret = ftw("/etc", callback, 1);

    return ret;
}
```

After modifying it to use captures:

```
int main()
{

    vector<string> entries;

    auto callback = [&](const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb,
        int typeflag) -> int {
        entries.push_back(fpath);
        return 0;
    };

    int ret = ftw("/etc", callback, 1);

    for (auto entry : entries ) {
        cout << entry << endl;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

I got the compiler error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘main()::<lambda(const char*, const stat*, int)>’ to ‘__ftw_func_t {aka int (*)(const char*, const stat*, int)}’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘int ftw(const char*, __ftw_func_t, int)’
```

After some reading. I learned that lambdas using captures **can't be implicitly converted** to function pointers.

Is there a workaround for this? Does the fact that they can't be "implicitly" converted mean s that they can "explicitly" converted? (I tried casting, without success). What would be a clean way to modify the working example so that I could append the entries to some object using lambdas?.

Comment: What compiler are you using? is it VS10?

Comment: gcc version 4.6.1 20110801 [gcc-4_6-branch revision 177033] (SUSE Linux)

Comment: Usually, the C way of passing state to callbacks is done via an extra argument to the callback (usually of type `void *`). If the library you are using allows for this extra argument, you will find a workaround. Otherwise, you have no way to achieve cleanly what you want to do.

Comment: Yes. I realize the api of ftw.h and nftw.h is flawed. I will try fts.h

Comment: Great! /usr/include/fts.h:41:3: error: #error "<fts.h> cannot be used with -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS==64"

Comment: @RamonZarazua. My compiler is Visual Studio 11.

Comment: @AlexandreC. It allows that. But I have issues to provide a clean API that only expects the lambda. I believe at least lambdas with capture clause must store a reference to their state.

Comment: The answers given here are correct but can't solve my actual problem. Therefore I formulated another, hopefully clearer, question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15748961/convert-lambda-with-capture-clause-stored-in-stdfunction-to-raw-function-point

Comment: please, remember that a capturing lambda has a lifetime. so many solutions here proposed are prone to error (i.e. segfault at runtime) if misused.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing capturing lambda as function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28746744/passing-capturing-lambda-as-function-pointer)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Since capturing lambdas need to preserve a state, there isn't really a simple "workaround", since they are *not* just ordinary functions. The point about a function pointer is that it points to a single, global function, and this information has no room for a state.

The closest workaround (that essentially discards the statefulness) is to provide some type of global variable which is accessed from your lambda/function. For example, you could make a traditional functor object and give it a static member function which refers to some unique (global/static) instance.

But that's sort of defeating the entire purpose of capturing lambdas.

Comment: A cleaner solution is to wrap the lambda inside an adapter, assuming that the function pointer has a context parameter.

Comment: @RaymondChen: Well, if you're at liberty to define how the function is to be used, then yes, that's an option. Though in that case it'd be even easier to just make the parameter an argument of the lambda itself!

Comment: @KerrekSB put the global variables in a `namespace` and mark them as `thread_local`, that's the `ftw` approach I chose for solving something similar.

Comment: "a function pointer points to a single, global function, and this information has no room for a state." -> How the hell can languages like Java accomplish this then? Well, of course, because that single, global function is created _at runtime_ and _embeds_ the state (or rather the _reference_ to it) in its own code. That **is** the whole point - there should _not_ be a _single, global function_ but _multiple_ global functions - one for each time lambda is used in runtime. Is there really NOTHING in C++ that does that? (I thought std::function is made exactly for that single purpose)

Comment: @Dexter: errr.. the short answer is no, the long answer involves operator overloading. Regardless, my point stands. Java is a different language that is not the same as C++; Java doesn't have pointers (or overloadable call operators) and the comparison doesn't work well.

Answer (score 56):

I just ran into this problem.

The code compiles fine without lambda captures, but there is a type conversion error with lambda capture.

Solution with C++11 is to use `std::function` (edit: another solution that doesn't require modifying the function signature is shown after this example).  You can also use `boost::function` (which actually runs significantly faster).  Example code - changed so that it would compile, compiled with `gcc 4.7.1`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

int ftw(const char *fpath, std::function<int (const char *path)> callback) {
  return callback(fpath);
}

int main()
{
  vector<string> entries;

  std::function<int (const char *fpath)> callback = [&](const char *fpath) -> int {
    entries.push_back(fpath);
    return 0;
  };

  int ret = ftw("/etc", callback);

  for (auto entry : entries ) {
    cout << entry << endl;
  }

  return ret;
}
```

Edit:
I had to revisit this when I ran into legacy code where I couldn't modify the original function signature, but still needed to use lambdas.  A solution that doesn't require modifying the function signature of the original function is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

// Original ftw function taking raw function pointer that cannot be modified
int ftw(const char *fpath, int(*callback)(const char *path)) {
  return callback(fpath);
}

static std::function<int(const char*path)> ftw_callback_function;

static int ftw_callback_helper(const char *path) {
  return ftw_callback_function(path);
}

// ftw overload accepting lambda function
static int ftw(const char *fpath, std::function<int(const char *path)> callback) {
  ftw_callback_function = callback;
  return ftw(fpath, ftw_callback_helper);
}

int main() {
  vector<string> entries;

  std::function<int (const char *fpath)> callback = [&](const char *fpath) -> int {
    entries.push_back(fpath);
    return 0;
  };
  int ret = ftw("/etc", callback);

  for (auto entry : entries ) {
    cout << entry << endl;
  }

  return ret;
}
```

Comment: No this should not be the accepted answer. The point is not changing `ftw` to take `std::function` instead of a function pointer...

Comment: The second solution proposed within this answer addresses the concern from @gregory-pakosz by preserving the original signature, but it's still not great because it introduces global state.

If `ftw` had a void* userdata argument, then I'd  prefer the answer from @evgeny-karpov.

Comment: @prideout agreed - I don't like the global state, either.  Unfortunately, assuming ftw's signature cannot be modified and given that it does not have void* userdata, state has to be stored somewhere.  I ran into this problem using a 3rd party library.  This will work fine as long as the library doesn't capture the callback and use it later, in which case the global variable simply acts like an extra parameter on the call stack.  If ftw's signature can be modified, then I'd prefer using std::function instead of void* userdata.

Comment: this is an extremely complicated and useful solution, @Gregory I should tell you "it works".

Answer (score 29):

**ORIGINAL**

Lambda functions are very convenient and reduce a code. In my case I needed lambdas for parallel programming. But it requires capturing and function pointers. My solution is here. But be careful with scope of variables which you captured.

```
template<typename Tret, typename T>
Tret lambda_ptr_exec(T* v) {
    return (Tret) (*v)();
}

template<typename Tret = void, typename Tfp = Tret(*)(void*), typename T>
Tfp lambda_ptr(T& v) {
    return (Tfp) lambda_ptr_exec<Tret, T>;
}
```

Example

```
int a = 100;
auto b = [&]() { a += 1;};
void (*fp)(void*) = lambda_ptr(b);
fp(&b);
```

Example with a return value

```
int a = 100;
auto b = [&]() {return a;};
int (*fp)(void*) = lambda_ptr<int>(b);
fp(&b);
```

**UPDATE**

Improved version

It was a while since first post about C++ lambda with captures as a function pointer was posted. As It was usable for me and other people I made some improvement.

Standard function C pointer api uses void fn(void* data) convention. By default this convention is used and lambda should be declared with a void* argument.

Improved implementation

```
struct Lambda {
    template<typename Tret, typename T>
    static Tret lambda_ptr_exec(void* data) {
        return (Tret) (*(T*)fn<T>())(data);
    }

    template<typename Tret = void, typename Tfp = Tret(*)(void*), typename T>
    static Tfp ptr(T& t) {
        fn<T>(&t);
        return (Tfp) lambda_ptr_exec<Tret, T>;
    }

    template<typename T>
    static void* fn(void* new_fn = nullptr) {
        static void* fn;
        if (new_fn != nullptr)
            fn = new_fn;
        return fn;
    }
};
```

Exapmle

```
int a = 100;
auto b = [&](void*) {return ++a;};
```

Converting lambda with captures to a C pointer

```
void (*f1)(void*) = Lambda::ptr(b);
f1(nullptr);
printf("%d\n", a);  // 101
```

Can be used this way as well

```
auto f2 = Lambda::ptr(b);
f2(nullptr);
printf("%d\n", a); // 102
```

In case return value should be used

```
int (*f3)(void*) = Lambda::ptr<int>(b);
printf("%d\n", f3(nullptr)); // 103
```

And in case data is used

```
auto b2 = [&](void* data) {return *(int*)(data) + a;};
int (*f4)(void*) = Lambda::ptr<int>(b2);
int data = 5;
printf("%d\n", f4(&data)); // 108
```

Comment: This is definitely the most convenient solution I have seen to convert a lambda to a C-style function pointer. The function taking it as an argument will just need an extra parameter representing its state, often named "void *user" in C libraries, so that it can pass it to the function pointer when calling it.

Comment: This solution works well in Arduino as well, where only a subset of C++ is available.

Comment: Is it possible to make this generic in regard to the number of lambda arguments? I tried something along the lines of `template <typename Tret, typename... Ts> static Tret lambda_ptr_exec(Ts... args) { ... }` but I'm unsure how to expand the parameter packs in the function.

Comment: It should be possible to achieve, however it does not look like it brings some benefits and definitely it makes implementation less readable. In case you would like to have a flexible structure without declaring it I would suggest to use std::tuple.

Answer (score 22):

Using locally global (static) method it can be done as followed

```
template <class F>
auto cify_no_args(F&& f) {
  static F fn = std::forward<F>(f);
  return [] {
    return fn();
  };
}
```

Suppose we have

```
void some_c_func(void (*callback)());
```

So the usage will be

```
some_c_func(cify_no_args([&] {
  // code
}));
```

This works because each lambda has an unique signature so making it static is not a problem. Following is a generic wrapper with variadic number of arguments and any return type using the same method.

```
template <class F>
struct lambda_traits : lambda_traits<decltype(&F::operator())>
{ };

template <typename F, typename R, typename... Args>
struct lambda_traits<R(F::*)(Args...)> : lambda_traits<R(F::*)(Args...) const>
{ };

template <class F, class R, class... Args>
struct lambda_traits<R(F::*)(Args...) const> {
    using pointer = typename std::add_pointer<R(Args...)>::type;

    static pointer cify(F&& f) {
        static F fn = std::forward<F>(f);
        return [](Args... args) {
            return fn(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        };
    }
};

template <class F>
inline typename lambda_traits<F>::pointer cify(F&& f) {
    return lambda_traits<F>::cify(std::forward<F>(f));
}
```

And similar usage

```
void some_c_func(int (*callback)(some_struct*, float));

some_c_func(cify([&](some_struct* s, float f) {
    // making use of "s" and "f"
    return 0;
}));
```

Comment: be aware that this will copy the closure (when getting the ptr) + args (when calling). Otherwise, it is a elegant solution

Comment: header-only helper library: https://gist.github.com/isc30/fab67e5956fe8f2097bed84ebc42c1e8

Comment: @IvanSanz-Carasa Thanks for pointing out. Closure types are not CopyAssignable, but functors are. So you right, it is better to use perfect forwarding here.
For args on other hand we can't do much as plain C does not support universal references, but at least we can forward values back to our lambda. This may save an extra copy. Has edited code.

Comment: @RiaD Yes, because lambda a static instance here you will need to capture by reference instead, e.g. instead of `=` use `&i` in your for-loop.

Comment: I've been looking for a way to do this for a LONG time... This solution still goes way over my head but this is amazing.

Comment: One specific thing that is confusing me is the use of `F::*`, what does this mean exactly?

Comment: @tjwrona1992 It is a pointer to a non-static member of class F (`F::operator()(...)` in this case), read more here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer

Comment: Which standard is required for this answer to work? clang 12 is complaining with "error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type name 'lambda_traits<F>::pointer'"

Comment: @VladimirNikishkin You are correct, there is a typo in return type. Fixed.

Comment: Marking the `static` variable as `thread_local` provides better thread-safety for the function.

Answer (score 4):

Hehe - quite an old question, but still...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

// We dont try to outsmart the compiler...
template<typename T>
int ftw(const char *fpath, T callback) {
  return callback(fpath);
}

int main()
{
  vector<string> entries;

  // ... now the @ftw can accept lambda
  int ret = ftw("/etc", [&](const char *fpath) -> int {
    entries.push_back(fpath);
    return 0;
  });

  // ... and function object too 
  struct _ {
    static int lambda(vector<string>& entries, const char* fpath) {
      entries.push_back(fpath);
      return 0;
    }
  };
  ret = ftw("/tmp", bind(_::lambda, ref(entries), placeholders::_1));

  for (auto entry : entries ) {
    cout << entry << endl;
  }

  return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution, just use a function pointer to refer to a static lambda.

```
typedef int (* MYPROC)(int);

void fun(MYPROC m)
{
    cout << m(100) << endl;
}

template<class T>
void fun2(T f)
{
    cout << f(100) << endl;
}

void useLambdaAsFunPtr()
{
    int p = 7;
    auto f = [p](int a)->int {return a * p; };

    //fun(f);//error
    fun2(f);
}

void useLambdaAsFunPtr2()
{
    int p = 7;
    static auto f = [p](int a)->int {return a * p; };
    MYPROC ff = [](int i)->int { return f(i); };
    //here, it works!
    fun(ff);
}

void test()
{
    useLambdaAsFunPtr2();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48368508/11470610) made by @vladimir-talybin has a little problem:

```cpp
template <class F>
auto cify_no_args(F&& f) {
  static F fn = std::forward<F>(f);
  return [] {
    return fn();
  };
}
```

That is, if the lambda is called twice in the function, then only the first call is valid, e.g.

```cpp
// only a demo
void call(std::vector<int>& nums) {
  static int i = 0;
  cify_no_args([&]() {
    nums.emplace_back(i++);
  })();
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> nums1, nums2;
  call(nums1);
  call(nums2);

  std::cout << nums1.size() << std::endl << nums2.size() << std::endl;
}
```

You will show the output of `2` and `0`, which means that the second call of `call` function is using the first call's lambda closure.

That's because the solution is using the static to store the closure's reference, and once the reference is stored, it won't be changed, even for a new closure. Things get worse if the closure will get destructed (due to out of scope or else).

My solution of this problem is simply turning the reference into pointer, and update the pointer's value every time we "construct" the lambda:

```cpp
template <class F>
auto cify_no_args(F&& f) {
  static typename std::remove_reference<F>::type* fn;
  fn = &f;
  return [] {
    return (*fn)();
  };
}
```

The overhead is two more memory access, one for read and one for write, but ensures the correctness.

Answer (score 1):

Spirited by the above answers of > [Jay West](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17305457/23065371) and > [Evgeny Karpov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33047781/23065371),
I get the following working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
template<typename TLambda, typename TStdFunction, 
         typename TRet, typename TCFunction>
struct LambdaPtrConverter {
public:
    explicit LambdaPtrConverter(TLambda&& pFun) { StdFun(&pFun); }
    explicit LambdaPtrConverter(TLambda& pFun) { StdFun(&pFun); }
protected:
    static TStdFunction StdFun(TLambda* pFun = nullptr) {
        static TStdFunction s_function;
        if (pFun) s_function = *pFun; 
        return s_function;
    }
    template<typename ... _Types>
    static TRet CFun(_Types... Args) {
        return StdFun()(std::forward<_Types>(Args)...);
    }
public: static TCFunction Ptr() { return (TCFunction)(CFun); }
};
//Following is helper function to void(void) function
typedef void (*FnVoidVoid)();
template<typename TLambda>
FnVoidVoid LambdaToVoidVoidFun(TLambda&& pFun) {
    return LambdaPtrConverter<TLambda, std::function<void()>, 
                              void, FnVoidVoid>(pFun).Ptr();
}  
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    const char* str = "hello world";
    FnVoidVoid pFun = LambdaToVoidVoidFun(
        [str]()->void { std::cout << str << std::endl; });
    pFun();     
    return 0;
}
```

The code is work, as the type of each lambda function is unique, and the LambdaPtrConverter instruction is unique for the input lambda function. It uses static std::function to store lambda function. If you need other types of functions, you can write another helper function, such as LambdaToVoidVoidFun above. For example, here is another type:

```
typedef void (*FnVoidIntInt)(int, int);
template<typename TLambda>
FnVoidIntInt LambdaToVoidIntIntFun(TLambda&& pFun)
{
    return LambdaPtrConverter<TLambda, std::function<void(int, int)>,
                              void, FnVoidIntInt>(pFun).Ptr();
}
```

And you can use it like this:

```
FnVoidIntInt pFun = LambdaToVoidIntIntFun(
    [str](int a, int b)->void {
        std::cout << str << std::endl;
        std::cout << a << std::endl;
        std::cout << b << std::endl;
});
```

***Be careful, the memory of the above static s_function will not be released,***
so this trick is only useful when you need to pass C style function pointer as entry points to some third-party frameworks, as these entry functions must always be loaded in memory before the program exits,
so this deficiency won't be a big problem

Answer (score 0):

There is a hackish way to convert a capturing lambda into a function pointer, but you need to be careful when using it:

https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79612/c-ifying-a-capturing-lambda

Your code would then look like this (warning: brain compile):

```
int main()
{

    vector<string> entries;

    auto const callback = cify<int(*)(const char *, const struct stat*,
        int)>([&](const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb,
        int typeflag) -> int {
        entries.push_back(fpath);
        return 0;
    });

    int ret = ftw("/etc", callback, 1);

    for (auto entry : entries ) {
        cout << entry << endl;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Found an answer here:
http://meh.schizofreni.co/programming/magic/2013/01/23/function-pointer-from-lambda.html

It converts `lambda pointer` to `void*` and convert back when needed.

1. to `void*`:

   auto voidfunction = new decltype(to_function(lambda))(to_function(lambda));
2. from `void*`:

   auto function = static_cast< std::function*>(
           voidfunction);

Comment: The link is no longer valid

Comment: The web archive has the link https://web.archive.org/web/20161012142308/http://meh.schizofreni.co/programming/magic/2013/01/23/function-pointer-from-lambda.html