# Phoenix::bind for C++11 lambdas in boost::spirit::qi semantic actions

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, boost-spirit

My goal is to create a workaround so that I may use C++11 lambdas inside Boost Spirit Qi semantic actions, while still having access to a more expanded set of qi placeholders, such as qi::_pass or qi::_r1, without having to manually extract them from the context object.  I wish to avoid writing Phoenix lambdas for some non-trivial parsing logic, preferring the more direct C++ syntax and semantics available inside C++11 lambdas.

The code below represents an idea I have for a workaround.  The idea is to use phoenix::bind to bind to the lambda and pass to it the particular placeholders I need.  However, I'm getting an extremely long templated compiler error (gcc 4.7.0, Boost 1.54) that I don't have the expertise to interpret.  I chose what I believe to be the most relevant portion and posted it below the code.

I'd like to know if what I'm trying to do in this code is possible with Boost Spirit, and if anyone can interpret the error message for me and tell me what's going wrong.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace spirit = boost::spirit;
namespace phoenix = boost::phoenix;

int main() {

    std::string input{"test1 test2 test3 FOO!"};
    typedef decltype(input.begin()) StringIter;

    qi::rule<StringIter, std::string()> parser =
        *(
            qi::char_
            [
                phoenix::bind(
                    [] (char value) {
                        std::cerr << value << std::endl;
                    },
                    qi::_1
                )
            ]
        );

    qi::parse(input.begin(), input.end(), parser);
}
```

(Note: I'm aware that the particular task performed by this code would be simpler with direct Phoenix constructs, or could even be done thanks to the Boost Spirit updates that allow a one-argument C++11 lambda directly, since it only uses the parsed value (qi::_1).  Nevertheless, it's a good minimal example of the kind of thing I'd like to do, and if I can get it to work, it should generalize easily.)

And, a bit of the compiler error (through STLfilt):

```
test\testSpiritLearning.cpp:28:9:   required from here
D:\programming\lib\boost\boost_1_54_0/boost/spirit/home/support/action_dispatch.hpp:178:13:
error: no match for call to '(
    const boost::phoenix::actor<
        boost::phoenix::composite<
            boost::phoenix::detail::function_eval<1>
          , boost::fusion::vector<
                boost::phoenix::value<main()::<lambda(char &)> >
              , boost::spirit::argument<0>, boost::fusion::void_
              , boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_
              , boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_
              , boost::fusion::void_, boost::fusion::void_
              , boost::fusion::void_
            >
        >
    >
) (
    boost::spirit::traits::pass_attribute<
        boost::spirit::qi::char_class<
            boost::spirit::tag::char_code<
                boost::spirit::tag::char_
              , boost::spirit::char_encoding::standard
            >
        >, char, void
    >::type &
  , boost::spirit::context<
        boost::fusion::cons<basic_string<char> &, boost::fusion::nil>
      , boost::fusion::vector0<>
    > &, bool &
)'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tell Boost that you want bleeding edge compiler support:<sup>[1]</sup>

```
#define BOOST_RESULT_OF_USE_DECLTYPE
```

and you wish to use the V3 version of Phoenix:

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
```

And it works

See it **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fb7f974b054d2c42)**

Reason:

- Using function objects in Phoenix *actors* assumes your function object will have a special nested *`struct result` template* or indeed a simple typedef `result_type`. This is known as the RESULT_OF protocol, see here:

  http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/utility.htm#result_of

  This protocol is required for c++03 compatibility. However, lambdas **don't have it**. In fact, lambdas have *unspecified types*. This is precisely one of the reasons why compilers with support for lambdas will always have `decltype` as well, so the RESULT_OF protocol is no longer required
- On the second `#define`, you need to select Phoenix V3, because Phoenix V2 simply doesn't implement support for lambdas. By default, Spirit V2 selects Phoenix V2 for historical/compatibility reasons. In practice, Phoenix V3 is just much more mature and fixes many (*many many*) problems, so I recommend always running with `BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3`

---

<sup>[1]</sup> might not be needed with very recent versions of some compilers

Comment: Thanks very much, that does indeed fix the compiler errors.  Out of curiosity, I also tried it with each addition commented out in turn; but it only worked with both un-commented.  Now I'm curious to understand _why_ that worked.

Comment: @anthrond Of course, I mentioned _both_ for a reason :) I've added a little explanation though. Cheers

Comment: So I've just noticed that it also compiles and runs correctly if I _don't_ wrap the lambda in the phoenix::bind(), but simply pass it directly to the semantic action (similar to some other questions I've seen, where Spirit now handles some lambdas with specific signatures), and remove the two `#define`s you added.  So, with your comment that only Phoenix V3 can handle lambdas, this leads me to the conclusion that Spirit can now handle lambdas directly, but not Phoenix V2, so introducing the layer of Phoenix V2 between Spirit and the lambda is what had led to my error.

Comment: @anthrond Yes. Just, you didn't _introduce_ that layer: Spirit is _married_ with Phoenix V2 by default. Even without `phx::bind` you will get Phoenix V2 only, implicitly. Also, check that semantics are actually the same. If it compiles, this doesn't mean that it does what you expect (lazy/non-lazy functions...). However, it _is_ possible that just passing a stateless lambda (uninvoked) works because of the implicit conversion to function pointer type. [see here e.g.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852101/c-lambda-with-captures-as-a-function-pointer)