# How attach context to c++ lambda

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, type-conversion, function-pointers

External API requires function `void foobar(void (*func)(void))`, and I can not change it.
How I can pass into this function another variables?

```
foobar([](){});
```

This code works fine.

```
foobar([this](){});
```

But this - not. Why?

Comment: Because `[this](){}` cannot be expressed as an ordinary function, it has state. Lambdas are no magic.

Comment: I understand that. So how I can do it? Maybe some std::bind/std::function magic?

Comment: You have to insert state into the function. For example, using `thread_local` storage, static storage, global storage, ... The interface of `foobar` simply is not flexible enough to support stateful function objects itself.

Comment: Anyway, as it stands, this is a duplicate question, [this Q/A](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7852154/420683) should be close enough to this question.

Comment: @Csq I don't quite like my superpowers, but well, if you agree... (edit: huh? oh, it wasn't *originally* tagged [c++])@ nkt You can ask a new, more specific question if you like. But in this general form, I think it already has been asked many times on StackOverflow.

Comment: The problem is that the external API is badly designed. Any decent interface would at least allow for a function plus context pointer.

Comment: [n3574](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3574.html) proposes adding similar functionality to the standard, but it isn't even near acceptance... Implementing it yourself involves runtime code generation.