# Passing capture-ful lambda to C-style callback through utility fn - error

Tags: c++

I'd like to pass a capture-ful lambda function to a C-style callback with a help of a utility function:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

struct AWS_IoT_Client {};
struct IoT_Publish_Message_Params {
    int payload[1024];
};

typedef enum {
    SHADOW_ACK_TIMEOUT, SHADOW_ACK_REJECTED, SHADOW_ACK_ACCEPTED
} Shadow_Ack_Status_t;

typedef enum {
    SHADOW_GET, SHADOW_UPDATE, SHADOW_DELETE
} ShadowActions_t;

typedef void (*pApplicationHandler_t)(AWS_IoT_Client *pClient, char *pTopicName, uint16_t topicNameLen,
                                      IoT_Publish_Message_Params *pParams, void *pClientData);

typedef void (*fpActionCallback_t)(const char *pThingName, ShadowActions_t action, Shadow_Ack_Status_t status,
                                   const char *pReceivedJsonDocument, void *pContextData);

struct AWS {
    inline void subscribe(char*, pApplicationHandler_t, void*)
    {
    }

    inline void get_shadow(fpActionCallback_t, void *)
    {
    }
};

AWS* aws = new AWS;

    namespace utils {
      template<class F>
      struct c_style_callback_t {
        F f;
        template<class...Args>
        static void(*get_callback())(Args..., void*) {
          return [](Args...args, void* fptr)->void {
            (*static_cast<F*>(fptr))(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
          };
        }
        void* get_pvoid() {
          return std::addressof(f);
        }
      };
      template<class F>
      c_style_callback_t< std::decay_t<F> >
      c_style_callback( F&& f ) { return {std::forward<F>(f)}; }
    }

int main() {
    char someVar[1024]={0};

    auto task2 = utils::c_style_callback(
      [&] (const char *pThingName, ShadowActions_t action, Shadow_Ack_Status_t status,
           const char *pReceivedJsonDocument, void *pContextData) {
        //sprintf(someVar, "%s", text);
      }
    );

    aws->get_shadow(
      task2.get_callback<const char*, ShadowActions_t, Shadow_Ack_Status_t, const char*, void*>(),
      task2.get_pvoid()
    );

    auto task = utils::c_style_callback(
      [&] (AWS_IoT_Client *pClient, char *topicName, uint16_t topicNameLen, IoT_Publish_Message_Params *params) {
        char *text = (char *)params->payload;
        sprintf(someVar, "%s", text);
      }
    );
```

However, I'm not getting error with a different callback:

```
    char topic[] = "some topic";
    aws->subscribe(
      topic,
      task.get_callback<AWS_IoT_Client*, char*, uint16_t, IoT_Publish_Message_Params*>(),
      task.get_pvoid()
    );
}
```

Error message:

> ```
> error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'fpActionCallback_t' (aka 'void (*)(const char *, ShadowActions_t, Shadow_Ack_Status_t, const char *, void *)') with an rvalue of type 'void (*)(const char *, ShadowActions_t, Shadow_Ack_Status_t, const char *, void *, void *)': different number of parameters (5 vs 6)
>       task2.get_callback<const char*, ShadowActions_t, Shadow_Ack_Status_t, const char*, void*>()`
> ```

I don't get why.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b921088fd13413f3)

## Update:

I would emphasize that the utility function `c_style_callback` can be very useful for others who encounter this issue in the future. It is a more flexible solution than the one in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852101/c-lambda-with-captures-as-a-function-pointer) as this one supports custom callback signature (not sure how to describe it).

My question was more about using it than the question about "lambda with captures as a function pointer".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ lambda with captures as a function pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7852101/c-lambda-with-captures-as-a-function-pointer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your callback definitions:

```
typedef void (*pApplicationHandler_t)(AWS_IoT_Client *pClient, char *pTopicName, uint16_t topicNameLen, IoT_Publish_Message_Params *pParams, void *pClientData);

typedef void (*fpActionCallback_t)(const char *pThingName, ShadowActions_t action, Shadow_Ack_Status_t status, const char *pReceivedJsonDocument, void *pContextData);
```

and the callback params in each case:

```
task.get_callback<AWS_IoT_Client*, char*, uint16_t, IoT_Publish_Message_Params*>()

task2.get_callback<const char*, ShadowActions_t, Shadow_Ack_Status_t, const char*, void*>()
```

In the first case you have an additional parameter `void* pClientData`, in the latter case you don't, even though `get_callback` will return a lambda with that additional parameter, because you return `return [](Args...args, void* fptr)`, not `return [](Args...args)`.

So either change your 2nd typedef to this:

```
typedef void (*fpActionCallback_t)(const char *pThingName, ShadowActions_t action, Shadow_Ack_Status_t status, const char *pReceivedJsonDocument, void *pContextData, void *pClientData);
```

or change the return type of `get_callback`.

Comment: Did you infer the `typedef`s from the diagnostics, or are they present in the "live example"?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf They are present in the "live example".