# How to use EnumWindows with a lambda?

Tags: c++, winapi

How to call the winapi `EnumWindows` in a lambda?
My attempt:

```cpp
        DWORD parentId;
        // ...
        HWND parent_hwnd;
        EnumWindows([parent_hwnd](HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
        {
            DWORD lpdwProcessId;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd,&lpdwProcessId);
            if(lpdwProcessId == lParam)
            {
                parent_hwnd = hwnd;
                return FALSE;
            }
            return TRUE;
        }, (LPARAM)&parentId);
```

Comment: You can only use non-capturing lambdas with Windows API functions. If you need to pass data into them you can use the `lParam` parameter.

Comment: @JonathanPotter could you give an example please?

Comment: @Natalia see the answer I just posted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`EnumWindows()` takes a plain ordinary C-style function pointer for its `lpEnumFunc` parameter.  However, a **capturing** lambda carries state information and thus is NOT convertible to a function pointer, since there is nowhere for the lambda to store its state in such a pointer.  Only a **non-capturing** lambda, which has no state, is convertible to a function pointer.

Note that you have two bugs in your original lambda, which would have caused your code to fail even if you could have used a capturing lambda as the callback:

- You are capturing the caller's `parent_hwnd` variable *by-value*, which means the lambda makes a *copy* and won't modify the value of the caller's original variable.  You would need to capture the variable *by-reference* instead.  Not that it matters in this case, since you can't use a capturing lambda anyway.
- (this one affects a non-capturing lambda, too) You are passing the caller's `parentId` variable by `DWORD*` pointer to the callback's `LPARAM`, but then you are treating the `LPARAM`'s value as-is, which means your comparison to each window's process ID will *never* find a match.  You would need to cast the `LPARAM` to a `DWORD*` pointer and then dereference that pointer in order to get the correct `DWORD` value for the comparisons, eg `if (lpdwProcessId == *(DWORD*)lParam)`.  Otherwise, just pass in the caller's `parentId` variable *by-value* instead of *by-pointer*, then you don't have to worry about this casting.  Not that it matters in this case, since you need to pass in more than just a single `DWORD` to the callback in order for your logic to work.

As such, you need to use a *non-capturing* lambda, and use the callback's `LPARAM` parameter to pass around *all* of your lambda's state information.

Try something more like this instead:

```
struct enumInfo {
    DWORD procId;
    HWND hwnd;
};

enumInfo info;
info.procId = ...;
info.hwnd = NULL;

EnumWindows(
    [](HWND hwnd, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        enumInfo *info = reinterpret_cast<enumInfo*>(lParam);

        DWORD dwProcessId;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd, &dwProcessId);

        if (dwProcessId == info->procId)
        {
            info->hwnd = hwnd;
            return FALSE;
        }
        return TRUE;
    },
    reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&info)
);

HWND parent_hwnd = info.hwnd;
// use parent_hwnd as needed...
```

Comment: Why isnt possible to capture parameters in the lambda when using with winapis?

Comment: @Natalia The Win32 API is based on C, and doesn't have the concept of a hidden `this` value which capturing lambdas rely on.

Comment: @Natalia See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7852154)

Comment: It is technically possible to implement a C-compatible stateful function by hiding its state inside of a thunk which is itself compatible with C-style function pointers. Some libraries do take advantage of this feature when using stateful objects with APIs that don't offer an `lParam`-like parameter. However, the C++ standard does not define such behavior for capturing lambdas at this time. Perhaps someone will propose such a feature in a future standard? Who knows.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually what I do when working with C APIs, provided they allow you to pass a context pointer (`lParam` in this case):

```
template<typename T>
BOOL EnumWindowsWrapper(const T &callback)
{
    return ::EnumWindows(
        [](HWND hWnd, LPARAM lParam)
        {
            auto &cb = *reinterpret_cast<decltype(&callback)>(lParam);
            return cb(hWnd, lParam);
        },
        (LPARAM)&callback);
}
```